# Jest test Stripe create customer in Next.js API route

Tags: next.js, jestjs, stripe-payments

I have a Next.js API handler where if the account doesn't have a Stripe customerId I create one. I want to be able to test if `stripe.customers.create` is being called or not with Jest.

**handler:**

```
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!, {
  apiVersion: "2022-11-15",
});

export default function handler(req, res) { 
  // some other code
  await stripe.customers.create();
}
```

**test:**

```
import { createMocks } from "node-mocks-http";
import handler from "../../../pages/api/stripe";

test("creates Stripe customerId if not exists", async () => {
  const { req, res } = createMocks({ method: "POST" });

  await handler(req, res);

  expect(stripe.customers.create).toHaveBeenCalled(); // how to test this?
});
```

What I don't know is how to mock Stripe in my test so that I can use the toHaveBeenCalled function in my test to see if it's been called or not.

I've found and tried a bunch of different ways to mock it, such as this:

```
jest.mock("stripe", () => {
  const stripe = jest.requireActual("stripe");
  jest
    .spyOn(stripe.resources.Customers.prototype, "create")
    .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ id: "stripe-test-id" }));
  return stripe;
});
```

But I can't figure out how to actually tie that into my test to see if it's called or not.